# Passing ajax call to variable ( jquery )

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any way I can run this code with async:false? I notice the jQuery manual specifies that it must be true, when passing the call return to a variable, but that is painful considering the method is meant to be generic.

```
ajaxCall.classFunction = function( $class, $function, $params){

//Ensure no errors occured
$params = typeof($params) != 'undefined' ? $params : false;

//Ajax Call for data
var $r =$.ajax({
    type:   'POST',
    url:    'json.php?c='+$class+'&func='+$function,
    data:   $params,
    timeout:5000,
    async:false,
}).responseText;
return $r;
```

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do here?  are you trying to POST the function to the PHP page, or do you want to call the function after POSTing?

Comment: You can set ajax calls to be synchronous by default via jQuery's [`$.ajaxSetup()`-method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). This is a bad idea in general, though.

Comment: @dave a js function which posts class/function/arguments to the server, which then executes said class/function with said arguements.

Comment: yes, take a look at the documentation, about halfway down is an example that uses a success handler: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will have to specify success callback. With async set to *true* your outer method is not blocked and returns immediately without waiting for the actual response for your ajax call.

Comment: did you mean: With async set to *true* your outer method is not blocked and returns immediately.

Comment: So what your saying is that it should be  possible to add a success handler which can then assign the output to a variable( or etc )?

Comment: Yes. Inside callback you can reference a variable that is declared outside it (you might want to read about closures - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). But your ajax call has to by synchronous.